# Proof of Corollary 1-1 "if m>1, then $n < m^n$" in Number Theory by George Andrews

Tags: algebra-precalculus

at the top of Page 6, the proof goes

> $n = 1 + .. + 1 \le 1 + m + m^2 + ... +m^{n-1} = \frac{m^n-1}{m-1} \le
>  m^n - 1 \le m^n $

What I didn't understand is this part

> $\frac{m^n-1}{m-1} \le m^n - 1$

Because if it's true, then

> $\frac{m^n-1}{m-1} \le m^n - 1 \Leftrightarrow 1 \le m-1
>  \Leftrightarrow 2 \le m $

But the condition is only m > 1

Can you explain why it's true? Thanks

Comment: $m>1$ is equivalent to $m\geq 2$.

Comment: I do not know the book, but could it be the case that $m \in \mathbb N$ is a natural number? Then $m>1 \Leftrightarrow m \geq 2$.

Comment: is $m$ an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $m$ is a natural number, $m > 1$ iff $m \geq 2$.

Comment: omg, you are right. I'm feeling stupid